# Recover password via MySQL (phpmyadmin)?

Tags: mysql, hash, phpmyadmin, passwords, md5

I have a script which uses this shop codecanyon.net/item/universal-digital-shop/2987770, however I have recently changed my password via it's admin panel front end(usually based on e.g. yoursite.com/settings.php) and did a silly move not check Notepad really saved my new password before closing it.

Now I cannot login to my shop at all and need help folks.

I check in phpmyamdin and it seems like its a hashed password (is it md5?), and I just don't know how these work.

I can post chunks of code and I have root access to mysql and phpmyadmin (Im more comfortable via phpmyadmin though and not a shell).

I don't want to populate the whole DB again as this will loose my customer records.

Any ideas?

The code below includes a password and an login ID. But the password "346g3643832823h2h39236323f263827" and login ID "admin" are only used for example purposes and are not the actual live pieces of data in the database.

```
<?php
/** DO NOT MODIFY OPTIONS BELOW. YOU CAN MODIFY THEM VIA ADMIN PANEL. */
define('VERSION', '2.50');
define('RECORDS_PER_PAGE', '50');
define('DEMO_MODE', false);
define('STATUS_DRAFT', 0);
define('STATUS_ACTIVE', 1);
define('STATUS_PENDING', 7);
define('ABSPATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

$options = array (
"version" => VERSION,
"owner_email" => "alerts@".str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]),
"from_name" => "Universal Digital Shop",
"from_email" => "noreply@".str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]),
"success_email_subject" => "Thank you for payment",
"success_email_body" => "Dear {payer_name},".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Thank you for your purchasing \"{file_title}\". Please find download link below:".PHP_EOL."{download_link}".PHP_EOL."This link is valid {download_link_lifetime} days.".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Thanks,".PHP_EOL."Universal Digital Shop",
"failed_email_subject" => "Payment was not completed",
"failed_email_body" => "Dear {payer_name},".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Thank you for your payment. Unfortunately, it was not completed.".PHP_EOL."Payment status: {payment_status}.".PHP_EOL."We will review your payment shortly.".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Thanks,".PHP_EOL."Universal Digital Shop",
"csv_separator" => ";",
"link_lifetime" => "2",
"xsendfile" => "off",
"enable_paypal" => "off",
"paypal_id" => "",
"paypal_sandbox" => "off",
"enable_payza" => "off",
"payza_id" => "",
"payza_sandbox" => "off",
"enable_interkassa" =>"off",
"interkassa_shop_id" => "",
"interkassa_currency" => "USD",
"interkassa_secret_key" => "",
"enable_authnet" => "off",
"authnet_login" => "",
"authnet_sandbox" => "off",
"authnet_key" => "",
"authnet_md5hash" => "",
"enable_skrill" => "off",
"skrill_id" => "",
"skrill_secret_word" => "",
"enable_egopay" => "off",
"egopay_store_id" => "",
"egopay_store_pass" => "",
"enable_perfect" => "off",
"perfect_account_id" => "",
"perfect_payee_name" => "",
"perfect_passphrase" => "",
"enable_bitpay" => "off",
"bitpay_key" => "",
"bitpay_speed" => "medium",
"enable_stripe" => "off",
"stripe_secret" => "",
"stripe_publishable" => "",
"login" => "admin",
"password" => "346g3643832823h2h39236323f263827"
);
$paypal_currency_list = array("USD", "AUD", "BRL", "CAD", "CHF", "CZK", "DKK", "EUR", "GBP",
"HKD", "HUF", "ILS", "JPY", "MXN", "MYR", "NOK", "NZD", "PHP", "PLN", "SEK", "SGD", "THB", "TRY",   

"TWD"););
$interkassa_currency_list = array("USD", "EUR", "GBP", "RUR", "UAH");
$egopay_currency_list = array("USD", "EUR");
$perfect_currency_list = array("USD", "EUR");
$bitpay_currency_list = array("USD", "EUR", "GBP", "AUD", "CAD", "CHF", "CNY", "RUB", "DKK", "HKD", "PLN", "SGD", "THB", "BTC");
$stripe_currency_list = array("USD", "CAD");
?>
```

Comment: Ask the vendor for support

Comment: Thanks for reply PeeHaa. It is was a project that was transferred to me and it's difficult to trace who actually acquired the script to begin with. Regards, Shuaib

Comment: search your source code after password, maybe you will find the code

Comment: Thanks Mikpa, that's the code there. Please note the password is not the actual password, I just wrote a random string for example purposes.

Comment: Also for note, that's the whole of the settings.php file. Does this help or do you need more code samples?

Comment: Mikpa, any thoughts then?

Answer (score 0):

Drop all tables in DB and repopulated them under same DB. Didn't need to worry too much about customer records anymore since Paypal held all my transaction records.

;)